# Properties of Transpose Matrices... Flippable?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, transpose

I'm learning linear regression using "A Primer on Linear Models" by John F. Monahan. On page 14, it says

$$Q(b) = (y-Xb)^T(y-Xb)=y^Ty − 2y^T Xb + b^T X^T Xb$$
Where $y$ is a $N ×1$ vector of observed responses, $X$ is a $N × p$ matrix of fixed constants, $b$ is a $p × 1$ vector of fixed but unknown parameters.

by developing brackets I can get $-y^TXb-(Xb)^Ty$. But I don't know from this how to get $− 2y^T Xb$ term. Why is it possible to just flip $(Xb)^Ty$ to $y^TXb$?

Also, on the same page 14,

$$\frac{d Q}{d b}=-2X^Ty + 2X^TXb = -2X^T(y-Xb)$$

I don't understand how I can get this result.

Comment: $X$ seems to be symmetric. So, $(Xb)^Ty = b^TXy$. Now, this is a number and numbers are invariant with respect to transposition. Hence, $b^TXy= (b^TXy)^T = y^TXb$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is well known that:

$$(MN)^T = N^T M^T.$$

Starting from this point, let's consider the transpose of $y^T Xb:$

$$(y^T Xb)^T = (y^T (Xb))^T = (Xb)^T (y^T)^T = (Xb)^T y.$$

Then,

$$-y^TXb-(Xb)^Ty = -2y^TXb = -2(Xb)^Ty.$$

Comment: Thanks! I understand the first and second lines. But $-y^TXb-(Xb)^Ty = -y^TXb-(y^TXb)^T$ and you cannot simply add up, right?

Comment: oh, $(y^TXb)^T$ is 1×1 so it's just a number? If so I can simply remove Transpose notation, right?

Comment: By the way, why is the gradient of $b^TX^TXb$(the last term) at $b$ is $2X^TXb$? Could you please guide me how to compute this?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus). It is very well written.